# Merge old account information with new account

Tags: discussion, user-accounts, merge-accounts

I had a Stack overflow account along with 160 reputations which was created with my previous company's email id and password. And now i have changed company and my previous company has blocked that email id and password and now am not able login to stack overflow account. I have created new account. How can i merge my previous account with my newly created account? Can u please help how can i get previous reputations?

Comment: @GGanesh, Please visit this link http://stackoverflow.com/help/user-merge

Comment: I red that answer before posting this question.They clearly mentioned that If you have access to both of your accounts,but i don't have my previous account access.

Comment: have you read the last line *If your issue was not covered above, please feel free to contact us directly.* ? Click on that link and mention your case in the textbox.